# Number of days in a month in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way to find the number of days in a month in DB2. For example I have a datetime field which I display as Jan-2020, Feb-2020 and so on. Based on this field I need to fetch the number of days for that month. The output should be something like below table,

I'm using the below query

`select reportdate, TO_CHAR(reportdate, 'Mon-YYYY') as textmonth from mytable`

Expected output

```
ReportDate       textMonth   No of Days
1-1-2020 08:00   Jan-2020      31
1-2-2020 09:00    Feb-2020     29
12-03-2020 07:00  Mar-2020     31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH MYTABLE (reportdate) AS 
(
VALUES
  TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 08:00:00')
, TIMESTAMP('2020-02-01 09:00:00')
, TIMESTAMP('2020-03-12 07:00:00')
)
*/
SELECT reportdate, textMonth, DAYS(D + 1 MONTH) - DAYS(D) AS NO_OF_DAYS
FROM
(
SELECT 
  reportdate, TO_CHAR(reportdate, 'Mon-YYYY') textMonth
, DATE(TO_DATE('01-' || TO_CHAR(reportdate, 'Mon-YYYY'), 'dd-Mon-yyyy')) D
FROM MYTABLE
);
```

Comment: I'm getting an syntax error while trying to do + 1 MONTH. When I simply try to execute DATE(TO_DATE('01-' || MONTH, 'dd-Mon-yyyy')) then it brings me a value say 737456 for FEB 2020. I do not understand what does +1 MONTH does.

Comment: If you uncomment the commented out block, you may run the statement as is. If it doesn't work, then provide your db2 platform and version, exact contents of your MYTAB table in form of "CREATE TABLE MYTAB ..."; "INSERT INTO MYTAB VALUES ...";

Comment: your sample query works in my database however I think the month is determined during runtime hence may be its working. I have updated the question , sorry I was not very clear.

Comment: @max092012 I've updated my answer according to your recent information.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 has the function [DAYS_TO_END_OF_MONTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061473.html) and several others which you could use. Based on your month input, construct the first day of the month. This should be something like `2020-01-01` for Jan-2020 or `2020-02-01` for Feb-2020. Follow the link for several other conversion functions which allow you to transform between formats and to perform date arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

convert your column to a proper date and try this: day(last_day(date_column))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).